# 64 bit and 32 bit issue in r and javaintegration

Tags: java, r, 64-bit

I have used R 64 bit and 64 bit machine, but it still complains of 32 bit. Not sure why it is saying IA 32-bit platform

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\Apps\Analytics\statistics\R\sdk\library\rJava
\jri\x64\jri.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
       at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
       at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.<clinit>(Rengine.java:19)
       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have 64 bit machine? What OS do you have?

Comment: Thank You Mocker it is Windows Ultimate : System Type: 64 bit Operating System

Comment: Strange! Can you perform the simple test, discribed in this video: [Windows 7 - How to determine your processor architecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9Y9yuXA-qA)? What result do you have? It seems that you have Windows 7 32 bit installed on hardware with 64-bit processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim, thank you for your clues. The issue was with my JDK was 32 bit, while OS was 64 bit and I had installed R with both 32 bit and 64 bit versions ticked during install.

```
The issue is gone, after uninstalling R and re-installing only 32 bit version of R. In short, when jdk is 32 bit use R 32 bit irrespective of OS
```

Comment: Depending on your RAM needs, I'd install the 64 bit version of Java and use the 64 bit version of R.